Is Gödel's incompleteness theorem a result of the requirement that the length of a sequence in a formal proof be "finite"?
I believe I understand the technical proof of Gödel's first incompleteness theorem, but even after thinking about it deeply, I still struggle to grasp the intuition behind the result.
I want to begin with a seemingly irrelevant question. We know that second-order arithmetic (AR2) -— here referring to the Peano axioms in second-order logic with standard semantics, not Henkin semantics —- is categorical. We also know that not every consistent second-order theory has a model. The proof of this fact (from Mendelson's textbook) is almost identical to the proof of the existence of nonstandard models for first-order Peano arithmetic. Specifically, this involves adding to AR2 the set of axioms $b \neq \bar{n}$ for all natural numbers $n$. The new theory is consistent if AR2 is consistent, because only a finite number of axioms $b \neq \bar{n}$ will be involved. Therefore, a contradiction cannot be derived. But the new theory does not have a model because AR2 is categorical.
This proof is quite puzzling to me because the entire issue arises from the fact that a formal proof only permits a finite sequence of symbols. For example, a sentence like $b \neq \bar{n}, n=0,1,2,3,...$, cannot appear in a formal proof.
Let me return to the question of Gödel's first incompleteness theorem. I will sketch the proof from the textbook I read (it is a standard mathematical logic textbook written in Chinese, by Fangting Wang). Let
$$W = \{(n_1,n_2) | n_1 \mbox{ is the Gödel number of some wf }p(x), n_2 \mbox{ is the Gödel number of the proof of } p(\bar{n}_1)\}.$$ Since $W$ is expressible in PA, let $w(x_1,x_2)$ be the corresponding wf. Let
$$ p(x_1) = \forall x_2 \neg w(x_1,x_2),$$ and denote its Gödel number by $m$. Then
$$ p(\bar{m}) = \forall x_2 \neg w(\bar{m},x_2)$$ is the unprovable statement we look for.
What puzzles me is it can indeed be proven that $PA \vdash \neg w(\bar{m}, \bar{n})$ for $n=0,1,2,...$. But $PA \nvdash \forall x_2 \neg w(\bar{m},x_2)$. This is particularly troubling to me in the context of second-order arithmetic because it is categorical.
In summary, the entire issue seems to be this: if a statement is true for every single natural number, then it is true for all natural numbers. However, having a formal proof for a certain statement for every single natural number does not mean that we have a formal proof for all natural numbers. That is again, because we only allow for a finite sequence of symbols in a formal proof.
Does this mean that formal logic has some shortcomings, or is it something deeper? I would greatly appreciate it if an expert could shed some light.

You are welcome to provide references to books or papers in languages other than English. Please do so in this case. As regards your question, it is certainly true that a system like PA can prove some statement $\phi_n$ parametrized by an integer $n$ for each $n$ (i.e., for each $n$ a proof exists) but not prove $\forall n.\phi_n$ (i.e., there is a proof that covers all possible $n$).
